# OAuth Google - Refresh Access Token - Unauthorized 401

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, oauth, google-oauth

I can't figure out why i can not refresh the access token from inside my application. Getting the access and refresh token from the api works like a charme but if i trie to gain a new access token from the google oauth api it tells me 401 Unauthorized and i don't know why.

The url i get back is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token?client_id=***********.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={*********}&refresh_token=**********&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

This is my Function for that:

```
function refreshAccessToken() {
    googleapi.authorize({
        client_id: clientID,
        client_secret: apiKey,
        refresh_token: localStorage.analyticsRefreshToken,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token'
    }).done(function(refData) {
        console.log(refData);
    })
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use a refresh token with javascript library nice to know.